# Talend read JSON data from tRESTRequest

Tags: talend

I am trying to learn Talend.

Scenario:
    I have to create a REST endpoint  (i am using `tRESTRequest`) which takes a POST request at `http://localhost:8086/emp/create` and accepts below json and prints each json field and sends a sample json response containing only `name` field.

1. How can I do so ?
2. How to read the json data into a java component like `tJava`?

Structure:

```
{
"emp" : 
 [ 
    {
      "id":"123",  
      "name": "testemp1"
    },
    {
        "id":"456", 
        "name": "testemp2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected Response:

```
{
"emp" : 
 [ 
    {
       "name": "testemp1"
    },
    {
       "name": "testemp2"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am using  `tRESTRequest -> tExtractJSONFields -> tRESTResponse`.

Answer (score 1):

For looping on the right elements and parsing the contents, please see my answer [JSON Deserialization on Talend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46884609/json-deserialization-on-talend/46886303#46886303)

I did not understand the second question. When deserializing JSON, the data will already be available in the usual row format for processing further. Beginner tutorials will show you the standard structure. The component `tJava` is - of course - an exception to that rule. Handling data is different in this component and not neccessarily row based.

Talend has an excellent knowledge base for components and examples, see https://help.talend.com/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If possible, can you share any example to using `tExtractJSONFields` with `tREStRequest`.

Comment: As stated before, please check the knowledge base. There is an example for the `tExtractJSONFields` component with a file component. You should be able to replace that with a `tRESTRequest` component and provide the json field there. Also in the knowledge base.

Comment: Here's a quick example I did to extract the name, using XPath, but you can use JSONPath if you prefer: https://imgur.com/a/PgArv

Comment: @iMezouar Thanks for the reply. I tried according to what you shared, replaced `tFileInput*` component with `tRESTRequest`. It works. I am able to read data and store in DB. I need to try with some complex json.

Comment: @tobi6 Thanks for the reply. Your valuable inputs helped me a lot. Thanks.

Comment: If this or another answer helped you, consider accepting the answer.